# Javascript Split() function won't return a value

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

Im really new to Java script, so please bear with me. I'm trying to write a script that will return a date with the addition of a user selected number of days. It works fine as far as returning a value (in the variable expDate, however the value is in the long format (i.e. "Wed Jan 02 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (HKT)) . I run into trouble when I try and break it down into different sections using split. Now my output is just blank.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setExpDate(){

var formDate = document.getElementById('startDate').value;
var number = +document.getElementById('days').value;


var interval = number;

var startDate = new Date(Date.parse(formDate));

var expDate = startDate;
expDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + interval);



var splitDate = expDate.split(' ');

var monthFomatted  = splitDate[1];
var dayFomatted  = splitDate[2];
var yearFomatted  = splitDate[3];


document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = monthFormatted;
document.getElementById('daysdays').innerHTML = Dateformatted;
};
</script>
</head>
```

HTML

```
<body>

<input type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" id="startDate" name="startDate" onblur="setExpDate(this.value)">

<select name="days" id="days" onchange="setExpDate(this.value)">
<option value="01">1</option>
<option value="02">2</option>
<option value="03">3</option>
<option value="04">4</option>
<option value="05">5</option>
<option value="06">6</option>
<option value="07">7</option>
</select>

 <div id="total"></div> <br/><div id="daysdays"></div>
</body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

`.split()` is a `String` method (that is it works on strings) and you are trying to use it on a `Date` object.

You'd be better to do

```
var monthFomatted  = expDate.getMonth();
var dayFomatted  = expDate.getDay();
var yearFomatted  = expDate.getYear();
```

`getMonth()`, `getDay()` and `getYear()` being methods that can be used on a Date object.

**EDIT**

Also note that you are setting `monthFomatted` then accessing `monthFormatted` which just isn't going to work. Check to make sure that variables are named consistently.